# Can't make navbar-right to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone explain me why the social network icons don't align to the right? I also can't change the .hundred and .word classes in CSS. Im trying to style the navbar-brand with two different styles. '100' with a style and 'words' with another one. Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16519/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1><span class="hundred">100</span><span class="word">words</span></h1></a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-facebook hidden-xs"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-twitter hidden-xs"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-instagram hidden-xs"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-pinterest hidden-xs"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `<ul ...>` outside `<div class="navbar-header">` right after it:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1><span class="hundred">100</span><span class="word">words</span></h1></a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
    ....
</ul>
```

Not clear what do you want to do with `.hundred` and `.word`. Probably u need append `display:inline-block` to both classes, then play with `padding`, and `<h1>` is not needed there.

Comment: I would like to style '100' and 'words' differently. Am I wrong using navbar-brand and trying to split it in two?

Comment: @rdvl0 `.nvabar-header` should be separate from menu as seen here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

Your navbar-header has not 100%-width  try:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header col-xs-12">
```

i forked it:
https://jsfiddle.net/d0h9gp6w/

Answer (score 0):

The social network links do align right, but the container of the social network does not stretch 100%, so they are at the right of what the container stretched.

You just need to add this: `.navbar-header {width: 100%;}`, here, I updated your JsFiddle :)

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16521/

Answer (score 0):

Add this Class

```
.navbar-header{width:100%}
```

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16523/)

Answer (score 0):

The `.navbar-header` has a media query attached to it that floats it to the left when the viewport is wider than 768px.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
  .navbar-header {
    float: left;
}
```

Giving `.navbar-header` width of 100% would take care of it, as mentioned above, or you could override that media query.